# Where to find specific additional information on meta?

Tags: support, specific-answer

An [A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86448/60716) to [Advertising for a hookah bar on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86430/advertising-for-a-hookah-bar-on-facebook)<sup>†</sup> has been locked with the message:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.

Where on meta is the additional information please?

<sup>†</sup> Since asking this here, Q has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original meta question has been closed and deleted. It was a rant about a comment that was made on the answer, and was largely impertinent and nonsensical.

I don't think it's worth dredging up, and the link could only be viewed by 10K members anyway. If you are truly curious, I can provided it to you.

Comment: That question is useless and should just be deleted.